# When trying to connect to Microsoft Azure from an external source I get the following error:

Tags: sql, azure

When trying to connect to Microsoft Azure from an external application source (SNAPPII) I get the following error:

I am using an XML template as supplied by SNAPPII tech support but they are unable to pinpoint the issue.

Can anyone help pinpoint the issue?

Error during query execution. Try to check the Data Source Configuartion.

Error : ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Reference to database and/or server name in ‘ODBC.dbo.TableName’ is not supported in this version of SQL Server

I have enclosed a code for xml file below.

I believe this type of connection should work with Microsoft Azure databases but to be honest I am a complete newbie in this environment.

```
<ext_db_settings>
<connection_strings>
  <connection_string name="foreland"><![CDATA[Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}; Server=tcp:ianm.database.windows.net; Database=foreland; Uid=ian.marks@ianm; Pwd=xxxxx; Encrypt=yes;]]></connection_string>
</connection_strings>
<query command="select" connection_string_name="foreland" type="sql" cache_timeout="0" max_size="5">
  <body><![CDATA[
    SELECT *
    FROM [ODBC].[dbo].[TableName]
  ]]></body>
</query>
<query command="add" connection_string_name="foreland" type="sql">
  <body><![CDATA[
    INSERT INTO [TableName]
    (
        Id,
        Name,
        Age,
        Residence
    )
    VALUES      
    (
        '[set.Id]',
        '[set.Name]', 
        '[set.Age]', 
        '[set.Residence]'
    )
  ]]></body>
</query>
```

Comment: settings>
  <ext_db_settings>
    <connection_strings>
      <connection_string name="foreland"><![CDATA[Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}; Server=tcp:ianm.database.windows.net; Database=foreland; Uid=ian.marks@ianm; Pwd=xxxxx; Encrypt=yes;]]></connection_string>
    </connection_strings>
    <query command="select" connection_string_name="foreland" type="sql" cache_timeout="0" max_size="5">
      <body><![CDATA[
     SELECT *
     FROM [ODBC].[dbo].[TableName]
   ]]></body>

Comment: Please edit your question with your settings - it doesn't belong in a comment, as it's pretty much unreadable due to lack of formatting. Turns out, your formatting was broken in the question - I fixed it for you.

Comment: Sorry and thanks David.